# JSF1064 gets more and more

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish

A Java web application with JSF2.2 and Primefaces 5 on glassfish 4.1.1.
Randomly glassfish/Primefaces produces
JSF1064: Unable to find or serve resource
The ressources are correct and at the right place.

The ressources are only Primefaces icons/css/js. I never got this error with my own css/js files.
After a browser refresh, the ressource will be delivered most of the time.

I think it can't be the googleable problem with threads and buffers, because normally the request will not serve the file but will be answered with a HTTP state 304. And, with a thread or buffer problem, I think it will occur with my files, too.

Another, possibly relating problem:

my session-bean contains

```
private String cuTheme = "aristo";
public String getCuTheme() { return cuTheme; }
```

web.xml contains

```
<context-param>
<param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
<param-value>#{sess.cuTheme}</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But in the following log, you can see many lines with i.e. `from library aristoxyz^@^@`.

Here comes a glassfish logfile of a every day working production environment.
After the last update Apr/02/2016 the errors got remarkably more.

```
[2014-09-30T08:30:26.596+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2014-09-30T08:30:26.596+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2014-09-30T08:30:31.899+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2014-09-30T08:30:31.899+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2014-09-30T08:30:33.555+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2014-09-30T08:30:33.556+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2014-10-30T07:03:48.754+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-01-02T11:17:06.076+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-01-02T11:17:06.077+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-01-02T11:17:06.076+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-16T09:39:34.717+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-16T09:39:34.717+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-16T09:39:34.717+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-17T15:28:56.433+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-17T15:28:56.435+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-17T15:28:58.471+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-17T15:28:58.471+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-17T15:28:58.471+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-24T10:39:08.868+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-24T10:39:08.881+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-24T10:39:08.896+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-02-24T10:39:08.911+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-03-23T12:50:43.500+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-03-23T12:50:43.528+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-03-23T12:50:44.005+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-03-25T17:13:29.629+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-04-27T22:15:19.193+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-04-27T22:15:19.212+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-04-27T22:15:19.225+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-04-27T22:15:19.285+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-05-04T09:47:10.065+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-05-05T09:51:10.435+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-05-05T09:51:10.499+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-05-29T09:39:27.328+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-05-29T09:39:27.330+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-05-29T09:39:27.330+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-05-29T09:39:27.335+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-06-17T15:08:15.514+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-06-17T15:08:15.519+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-07-01T10:41:02.439+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-07-01T10:41:05.193+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-07-01T10:41:05.197+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-08-28T10:55:33.899+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-01T08:25:11.752+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-01T08:25:11.754+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-01T08:25:11.752+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-01T08:25:11.753+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-01T09:33:22.443+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-01T09:33:22.552+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T08:59:28.581+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T08:59:28.588+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource theme.css aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T08:59:28.591+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T08:59:28.606+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T09:01:16.538+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T09:01:16.548+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T09:01:16.554+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-17T09:01:16.568+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource theme.css aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-23T08:43:22.832+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-23T08:43:22.833+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-09-23T08:43:22.832+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-10-12T12:52:05.671+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-10-12T12:52:05.689+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-10-27T10:02:55.622+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-10-27T10:02:55.625+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-10-27T10:02:55.626+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-11-10T10:23:23.935+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-11-10T10:23:24.107+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-16T11:39:35.459+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-16T11:39:35.473+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-16T11:39:36.525+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-16T11:39:36.532+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-16T11:39:36.749+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-16T11:39:36.753+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-16T11:39:38.645+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-18T10:03:45.060+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2015-12-18T10:03:45.066+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-19T09:27:03.083+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-19T09:27:03.086+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-19T09:27:03.085+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-19T09:27:03.084+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-21T08:51:37.387+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-21T08:51:37.387+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-26T09:22:02.859+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-26T16:41:15.485+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-01-26T16:41:15.506+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-08T13:06:14.475+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-10T13:44:22.900+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-16T13:47:11.882+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-17T10:10:47.103+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-17T10:10:48.223+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-18T09:02:58.708+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-18T09:02:58.705+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource css/global.css kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-18T09:02:58.717+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-18T09:02:58.726+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-18T09:02:58.728+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-18T11:32:15.863+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-29T08:34:31.442+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-02-29T08:34:31.445+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-04T12:48:54.578+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-04T12:48:54.814+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-04T12:48:54.825+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-08T09:42:52.631+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-08T09:42:52.634+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-08T09:42:52.642+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-08T09:42:52.653+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource theme.css aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-23T09:20:29.428+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-23T09:20:29.428+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-24T09:51:17.691+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-24T09:51:17.706+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-24T13:06:07.184+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-24T13:06:07.319+0100] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-29T10:40:06.166+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-29T10:40:06.218+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-29T15:12:56.119+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-29T15:12:56.120+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-29T15:54:19.141+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-29T15:54:19.157+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-30T17:01:43.660+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-03-30T17:01:43.721+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-01T09:30:10.732+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-01T09:30:10.761+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-02T13:37:22.751+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-02T13:37:22.752+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-02T13:37:22.762+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-02T13:37:23.082+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T08:33:20.281+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T08:33:27.526+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T09:45:40.714+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces072isto kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T09:48:58.493+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T09:52:20.811+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T09:52:20.829+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T09:58:23.937+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource theme.css aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristojYucGRm kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T10:15:12.289+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T10:15:12.300+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T10:34:58.355+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource theme.css kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T11:20:20.265+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristojMucGRm= kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T11:23:37.685+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces145istojYu kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T11:23:42.562+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristojUu kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T11:31:33.185+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T12:19:22.376+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T12:59:00.611+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T13:05:42.902+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo2ho kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T13:15:15.378+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T13:18:09.342+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristoA0N kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T13:26:08.590+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T13:27:09.027+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces691isto2ho kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T13:55:11.074+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T13:58:12.555+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo2ho kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T14:30:57.706+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo2ho kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T14:34:47.473+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T14:38:52.380+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery-plugins.js kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T14:38:56.345+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource fileupload/fileupload.css kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T14:44:32.689+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource images/ui-bg_inset-hard_65_85b2cb_1x100.png kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T14:54:48.999+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces753isto2ho kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T15:13:26.799+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-04T15:54:16.050+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-05T07:36:14.631+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource jquery/jquery.js kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-05T09:12:43.064+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.css aus Bibliothek primefaces068isto2ho kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
[2016-04-05T09:14:29.694+0200] [[ JSF1064: Ressource primefaces.js aus Bibliothek primefaces-aristo2ho kann nicht gefunden oder bedient werden.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it. My problem based on using class-variables in a filter class.

Comment: If you could add some more details on how you fixed your specific case, that would be nice :)